# Remove text from a textfile c#

Tags: c#, text, listbox

I have some code that i need to remove from a text file and store in a listbox 
Here is the code:

```
   Version=106
Monitor=34
SMode=111111100
Date=20130205
StartTime=15:46:20.0
Length=01:06:18.9
Interval=1
Upper1=0
Lower1=0
Upper2=0
Lower2=0
Upper3=180
Lower3=170
Timer1=00:00:00.0
Timer2=00:00:00.0
Timer3=00:00:00.0
ActiveLimit=0
MaxHR=195
RestHR=46
StartDelay=0
VO2max=48
Weight=66

[Note]

[IntTimes]
00:09:59.0  117 91  127 153
0   0   0   124 41  309
0   0   0   0   0
0   2181    68  0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0
00:10:00.0  115 91  127 153
0   0   0   119 0   309
0   0   0   0   0
33554432    2184    0   0   0   0
500 0   0   0   0   0
00:20:10.0  173 109 161 177
0   0   0   112 62  307
0   0   0   0   0
0   3461    22  0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
00:25:02.0  119 111 126 172
0   0   0   190 54  308
0   0   0   0   0 
0   764 133 0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
00:35:16.0  174 119 167 179
0   0   0   121 52  309
0   0   0   0   0
0   3500    70  0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
00:50:00.0  134 109 153 179
0   0   0   178 0   310 
0   0   0   0   0
33554432    10840   0   0   0   0
500 0   0   0   0   0
01:00:00.0  150 112 139 175
0   0   0   66  0   312
0   0   0   0   0
33554432    1741    0   0   0   0
500 0   0   0   0   0
01:06:18.9  108 105 139 177
0   0   0   64  123 313
0   0   0   0   0
0   5668    0   80  0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0

[IntNotes]
1   
2   
3   
4   
5   
6   
7   
8   

 [ExtraData]

[LapNames]
1   1   
2   4   
3   1   
4   1   
5   1   
6   4   c
7   4   
8   1   

[Summary-123]
3978    0   3978    0   0   0
195 0   0   46
3978    0   3978    0   0   0
195 0   0   46
0   0   0   0   0   0
195 0   0   46
0   3978

[Summary-TH]
3978    0   0   588 3390    0
195 180 170 46
0   3978

[HRZones]
190
175
162
152
143
133
0
0
0
0
0

[SwapTimes]

[Trip]
250
0
3978
309
313
229
504
651
//n header

[HRData]
```

I need to remove the data from: 
Upper1 =0
TO 
[HRData] 
and store this in my listbox1 so that it doesnt display in my datagridview

I have tried using the topindex function but to no avail 
I get the error

Appriciate the help thanks

Comment: File.ReadAllLines to get an array of lines, loop examining each one only adding once you have passed Upper1=0

Comment: @AlexK. i use a streamreader to read each line 1 at a time, is there anyway to do it using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written by Alex, a very simple code is:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines("TextFile1.txt")
                     .SkipWhile(x => x != "Upper1=0")
                     .TakeWhile(x => x != "[HRData]")
                     .ToArray();
```

Using the `StreamReader` it's a little more complex (but not so much)

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
bool skipping = true;

using (var sr = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt")) {
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
        line = line.TrimEnd();

        if (skipping) {
            if (line == "Upper1=0") {
                skipping = false;
            }
        }

        if (!skipping) {
            lines.Add(line);

            if (line == "[HRData]") {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The things that before where done by `SkipWhile`/`TakeWhile` now are done by a flag `skipping`

(in both cases both `Upper1=0` and `[HRData]` are taken in the collections)

This is a small variant on the `StreamReader` version. It implements a very simple state machine (I do know, I'm very lazy, I should have used an `enum` and not an `int`) to split the lines between the "before", the "middle" and the "after".

```
List<string> linesBefore = new List<string>();
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
List<string> linesAfter = new List<string>();

// 0 = before Upper1=0, 
// 1 = between Upper1=0 and [HRData]
// 2 = after [HRData]
int state = 0;

using (var sr = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt")) {
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
        line = line.TrimEnd();

        if (state == 0) {
            if (line == "Upper1=0") {
                state = 1;
                lines.Add(line);
            } else {
                linesBefore.Add(line);
            }
        } else if (state == 1) {
            lines.Add(line);

            if (line == "[HRData]") {
                state = 2;
            }
        } else {
            // state == 2
            linesAfter.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better is to use `File.ReadLines()` which doesn't buffer the entire file in memory. (Not significant for such a small file, but good practice.) Also I think you  might have the SkipWhile and TakeWhile the wrong way around.

Comment: @MatthewWatson True! :-) Done :-)

Comment: Ah they aren't the wrong way around, but the question is misleading: It says "I need to remove the data from..." but it really means "I need to copy the data from...", which is what your code does correctly. (Other than your code doesn't include the `[HRData]` line in the output, which may or may not be what he wants.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yep... I interpreted the "remove" to "copy", considering the part that spoke about a ListBox.

Comment: @xanatos is there anyway of removing the information from being read into the program but without removing it from the actual text file? Thanks

Comment: @KingKong What do you mean? Do you want in an array the lines before `Upper1=0` and after `[HRData]`?

Comment: @xanatos after HRData i have 6 columns of data all seperate by \t (tab) that i need storing in an array then to populate a datagridview, I have set up an array that reads all lines in text file so i need to remove irrelevant data a.k.a this question. sorry if this is confusing

Comment: @KingKong I've added a new version that returns the lines before and after.

Answer (score 0):

This example

```
Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\MyIniFile.txt"),  // Read all lines into buffer.
               @"(Upper1=0)(.*)(\[HRData\])",         // Set upper to HRData to be removed
               string.Empty,                          // 'replace' the section with a empty line
               RegexOptions.Singleline)
      .Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },           // Split the remaining buffer into lines
             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // Don't show empty lines.
```

1. Reads all lines into a buffer from a file.
2. Uses regex replace to remove the section required.
3. Splits the remaining lines into an array of lines while removing any blank lines (remove that if blanks are to be shown).